# Display Correct Radio Button Value Not Working with Default Checked Option?

Tags: javascript, events, input, radio-button

**Problem: Default checked radio button value shows on app, but if I change the tip value, then unselect and reselect a checkbox, it goes back to the original checked radio button value instead of changing to the new tip value.**

Basicaly, my default radio checked button value is set to `$5`. If I select a checkbox option, then I change the tip value to `$2` then unselect a checkbox, then reselect a checkbox, it will show the tip value as `$5` instead of the new option `$2`

Here's my codepen. I added instructions on the codepen so you can see my problem

https://codepen.io/jaysomo10/pen/dydaKwZ

Here's my JS

```
window.menuItems = 0;
window.tips = 0;

const foodTotal = document.getElementById("price");
const tipTotal = document.getElementById("tip");
const orderTotal = document.getElementById("total");

let tipVal = document.querySelector(".tips:checked").value;

tipTotal.textContent = "$" + (tipVal / 100).toFixed(2);

document.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
  if (target.className === "food" && target.checked && tipVal) {
    window.menuItems += parseInt(target.value);
    window.tips = tipVal;
  } else if (target.className === "food" && !target.checked) {
    window.menuItems -= parseInt(target.value);
  } else if (target.className === "tips" && target.checked) {
    window.tips = parseInt(target.value);
  } else {
    return;
  }

  foodTotal.textContent = `$${(window.menuItems / 100).toFixed(2)}`;
  tipTotal.textContent = `$${(window.tips / 100).toFixed(2)}`;
  orderTotal.textContent = `$${(
    (Number(window.menuItems) + Number(window.tips)) /
    100
  ).toFixed(2)}`;
});
```

I can't seem to convert the logic to make the tip value to change after I unselect & re select a checkbox option.

Answer (score 0):

tipVal is defined outside the click event. So it has always the value at the sart. You have to changhe it also inside the event

```
window.menuItems = 0;
window.tips = 0;

const foodTotal = document.getElementById("price");
const tipTotal = document.getElementById("tip");
const orderTotal = document.getElementById("total");

let tipVal = document.querySelector(".tips:checked").value;
tipTotal.textContent = "$" + (tipVal / 100).toFixed(2);

document.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
  tipVal = document.querySelector(".tips:checked").value;
  if (target.className === "food" && target.checked && tipVal) {
    window.menuItems += parseInt(target.value);
    window.tips = tipVal;
  } else if (target.className === "food" && !target.checked) {
    window.menuItems -= parseInt(target.value);
  } else if (target.className === "tips" && target.checked) {
    window.tips = parseInt(target.value);
  } else {
    return;
  }

  foodTotal.textContent = `$${(window.menuItems / 100).toFixed(2)}`;
  tipTotal.textContent = `$${(window.tips / 100).toFixed(2)}`;
  orderTotal.textContent = `$${(
    (Number(window.menuItems) + Number(window.tips)) /
    100
  ).toFixed(2)}`;
});
```

Comment: is it normal to define the same value twice?

Comment: @joesono1 it is a variable and it changed during the program. Otherwise you have to make an observer but it is not worth it for this application. Only const  values cannot be redefined

Answer (score 0):

remove this from your first if statement

```
if (target.className === "food" && target.checked && tipVal) {
    window.menuItems += parseInt(target.value);
    //window.tips = tipVal; // remove this
  }
```

Comment: that doesn't show the tip then

Comment: it does work as expected check this https://codepen.io/aman4404/pen/VwQgBxq

Comment: the tip value isn't showing the default checked option

Comment: Not sure what r u referring to

Comment: did you not read my problem in the codepen?